# Getting log file of system ON & OFF history

Tags: 12.04, log, history

How i can get the log-file of Ubuntu 12 Shutdown, Restart and Start history , I tried with "last UserNanme" in terminal but not getting the data i want, Please help me to find the log file .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Maybe You're looking for `~/.xsession-errors`?

Also take a look at `~/.bash_history`.

Comment: I want the log file in where the login and log off data stored, I gt that from Auth file thank for helping